# MarkLogic json:transform-to-json config to skip XML root element

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I'm using MarkLogic json:transform-to-json to produce JSON from XML. I can't figure out the right config options to skip the root element in the XML, and only show the immediate children and further descendants.

**I do**

```
import module namespace json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"
 at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

let $jsonConfig := json:config("custom")
    => map:with("whitespace","ignore")
    => map:with("array-element-names",'genre')

let $payLoad := 
  <root>
    <name>The Beatles</name>
    <genre>rock</genre>
    <genre>pop</genre>
    <genre>beat</genre>
    <genre>psychedelia</genre>
  </root>

return json:transform-to-json($payLoad,$jsonConfig)
```

**I get**

```
{
  "root": {
    "name": "The Beatles", 
    "genre": [
        "rock", 
        "pop", 
        "beat", 
        "psychedelia"
        ]
    }
}
```

**I want to get**

```
{
    "name": "The Beatles", 
    "genre": [
        "rock", 
        "pop", 
        "beat", 
        "psychedelia"
        ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I note that the sample does not run as expected.  I think you meant this line for the config: `=> map:with("array-element-names",'genre')`

As for what you are doing: If you are storing this in MarkLogic, then I would urge you to keep the extra level at the top with "root". This will play well with some items in MarkLogic like the "context" for TDE templates.

However if you prefer to remove it, there is no configuration - instead, simply x-path to what you want:

```
import module namespace json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"
 at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

let $jsonConfig := json:config("custom")
    => map:with("whitespace","ignore")
    => map:with("array-element-names",'genre')
    

let $payLoad := 
  <root>
    <name>The Beatles</name>
    <genre>rock</genre>
    <genre>pop</genre>
    <genre>beat</genre>
    <genre>psychedelia</genre>
  </root>

return json:transform-to-json($payLoad,$jsonConfig)/root
```

Resulting in:

```
{
    "name": "The Beatles", 
    "genre": [
        "rock", 
        "pop", 
        "beat", 
        "psychedelia"
    ]
}
```

Comment: OBVIOUSLY, I don't know why I didn't think of this :D Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: No Problem.  Sometimes its a bit confusing related to javascript and x-path from xQuery.  It makes sense that it works.. It just sort of feels odd :)